How to generate point cloud using depth image in drake simulation
I'm currently working on setting up a simulation environment using Drake in Python. My goal is to load various objects into the scene and generate a point cloud from a depth camera. While I've successfully set up the environment and managed to obtain the depth map, I'm struggling with generating a point cloud using DepthImageToPointCloud or any alternative methods.
I've referred to tutorials and documentation, including this example for getting a depth image, but haven't found a suitable implementation for generating point clouds.
Could someone provide guidance or point me to a resource that demonstrates how to implement point cloud generation from depth images within the Drake simulation environment?

There are a number of examples in my manipulation course notes.  For example, you can check out this example performing normal estimation from depth.
The setup of the DepthImageToPointCloud system happens in the MakeHardwareStation method, which you can find here.
Then the point cloud is obtained by e.g. pulling out the output port:
point_cloud = diagram.GetOutputPort("camera0_point_cloud").Eval(context)

